# Enter 'assume-role'' in terminal not working, display killed message

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, homebrew, assume-role

I have a project that will need to use assume-role to get AWS permissions.

Usually I will use the command `eval $(assume-role -duration 8h0m0s profile_name)` to get permission, and the terminal will prompt me to enter the MFA verification code after inputting

But after I upgraded Mac OS13, this command doesn't work anymore

I tried using `assume-role` to make sure it worked, but got a response like `[1] 35413 killed assume-role`.

Also I have confirmed with `aws sts get-caller-identity` that I have the correct AWS role.

I also reinstalled assume-role via brew and upgraded brew at the same time.

I would like to ask how to fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using AWS CLI: like below command

```
eval $(aws sts assume-role --profile {{YOUR_PROFILE}} --role-arn {{YOUR_ROLE_ARN}} --role-session-name {{CUSTOM_SESSION_NAME}}
--serial-number {{YOUR_SERIAL}} --duration-seconds 28800 --token-code {{YOUR_MFA_CODE}} | jq -r '.Credentials | "export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\(.AccessKeyId)\nexport AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\(.SecretAccessKey)\nexport AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\(.SessionToken) AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN=\(.SessionToken)\n"')
```

You can check these info in .aws/config and .aws/credentials

Comment: whats {{YOUR_SERIAL}} ?
this is not present in either config or credentials file